# No backend login possible

Tags: authentication, backend, impresspages

I can`t login in the backend. If i try, I get this:

Menu
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Ip\CoreException' with message 'Can't find view file '/data/web/1/000/040/926/146548/htdocs/ideengold-texter/ip_cms/includes/Ip/Module/Admin/View/bootstrapNav.php' (Error source: /data/web/1/000/040/926/146548/htdocs/ideengold-texter/ip_cms/includes/Ip/View.php line: 444 )' in /data/web/1/000/040/926/146548/htdocs/ideengold-texter/ip_cms/includes/Ip/View.php:327 Stack trace: #0 /data/web/1/000/040/926/146548/htdocs/ideengold-texter/ip_cms/includes/Ip/View.php(44): Ip\View::findView('/data/web/1/000...') #1 /data/web/1/000/040/926/146548/htdocs/ideengold-texter/ip_cms/includes/Ip/View.php(444): Ip\View::create('/data/web/1/000...', Array) #2 /data/web/1/000/040/926/146548/htdocs/ideengold-texter/ip_cms/includes/Ip/Module/Admin/View/toolbar.php(17): Ip\View->generateMenu('admin_navigatio...', Array, 'bootstrapNav.ph...') #3 /data/web/1/000/040/926/146548/htdocs/ideengold-texter/ip_cms/includes/Ip/View.php(204): require('/data/web/1/000...') #4 /data/web/1/000/040/926/146548/htdocs/ideengold- in /data/web/1/000/040/926/146548/htdocs/ideengold-texter/ip_cms/includes/Ip/View.php on line 327

Please help. 
Thank you
Thorsten

Comment: Please provide more context and formulate a concrete question so others can help you

Comment: Hello Mr. Ey! Thank you. Its all about my page www.ideengold.de and all my other domains, where i installad impresspages. My question is: What can I do, to login in the backend again. Thank you Thorsten Simon

Comment: What did you do before this started to happen?

Comment: I write www.ideengold.de/admin. Than the login-formular comes. Than I write my login-data in this. and then this text from above appears. What can I do? Thanx Thorsten

Answer (score 0):

This view doesn't exist: View/bootstrapNav.php

Try to download the same theme and upload the view/file.

If it's the default theme, try downloading once more ImpressPages and upload just that view/file. Hope it helps!